# WSDL Null Response .NET but returns values on SoapUI

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soapui, service-reference

I am having an issue where the I have an imported wsdl service reference that returns null on .net visual studio but values are returned normally on soapui in the response. the response has encoded " < " in the xml so I don't know if this is causing the issue where c# doesn't interpret it.

I tried running on soap and response is returned normally with the "lt;" annotation in it but null on c#. other requests and responses are returned normally and valid on both soapui and c# which don't have the "<".

Comment: did you try and create a web reference rather than a service reference?  Are you targeting net 4.8 or below or what?

Comment: if you are getting a null than server did not send a response.  It means the connection did not complete because a server will send an error message with a failure status otherwise.  This sound more like you are using HTTPS and the TLS is failing.  Are you connecting between the same client machine and same server machine when working and not working?

Comment: all other requests work and response is returned successfully, this only happens if a specific request that returns null from server on vs code but returns normally on soapui, been on it for 3 days and nothing if anyone has any other ideas. i tried using web reference on a sperate .net 4.7.2 project and still same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Updated: solved it by using java springboot c# returned null response because it could not decode the xml when the response message contained < I consumed the wsdl on java spring boot using maven dependencies and using spring web, imported the wsdl and then the outputted classes were used to send and set the request and the response was returned without any issues and spring decoded the < from the xml schema.